# applying for loop such that counters are multiplied rather than being added in python

Tags: python, for-loop

hello I am relatively new to python! Is there a way to do this using for loops in python?
This is a java implementation of something i want to do in python

```
for (i=1;i<20; i*= 2)
{System.out.println(i);}
```

Solution in while loop in python`

```
while i<20:
    print i
    i*=2
```

I cannot figure out a way to do this using for loops. Implemented it using while loop obviously, but still curious to know whether there is a method to do so or not

Comment: I assume you mean `i *= 2`?

Comment: It would give a rather good impression if you showed us the `while` loop version. Did you even try searching anything? Maybe google "Python for loop tutorial" to get started?

Comment: yes i tried searching, and could not find anything satisfactory! and editing the code

Comment: Something like this, but your question is not very clear. `for i in range(1, 20): print(i*2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, e.g.

```
for i in range(5):
    i = 2 ** i
    print i
```

or using generators

```
from itertools import count, takewhile

def powers_of_two():
    for i in count():
        yield 2 ** i

for i in takewhile(lambda x: x < 20, powers_of_two()):
    print i
```

But in the end, it depends on your use case what version gives the clearest and most readbale code.  In most cases, you would probably just use a while-loop, since it's simple and does the job.

Comment: I thought of the first case but uper limit 20 for the loop was selected randomly, it could be anything for my purpose, so it was really getting complicated to implement that in my case. Lambda expressions however, solves it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You think of `for` loops like they would be in other languages, like C, C++, Java, JavaScript etc.

Python `for` loops are different; they work on *iterables*, and you always have to read them like:

```
for element in iterable
```

instead of the C'ish

```
for(start_condition; continue_condition; step_statement)
```

Hence, you would need iterable to generate your products.

I like readability, so here's how I'd do it:

```
for a in (2**i for i in range(20)):
    print a
```

But that mainly works because we mathematically know that the i'th element of your sequence is going to be `2**i`.

Comment: I really dislike the `for x in (generator expression):` idiom.  It unnecessarily contains two for-loops in the same line and can always be written as `for i in range(20): a = 2 ** i`, which I find much simpler and clearer.

Comment: Oh, and note that your loop is different from the OP's loop.  The OP's loop stops at 16, yours at 2**19.

Comment: yes, you got me right, I am from java background and was assuming it works the same. Thankyou! :D

Answer (score 1):

There is not a real way to do this in Python. If you wanted to mimic the logic of that for loop exactly, then a manual while loop would definitely be the way to go.

Otherwise, in Python, you would try to find a generator or generator expression that produces the values of `i`. Depending on the complexity of your post loop expression, this may require an actual function.

In your case, it’s a bit simpler because the numbers you are looking for are the following:

```
1 = 2 ** 0
2 = 2 ** 1
4 = 2 ** 2
8 = 2 ** 3
...
```

So you can generate the numbers using a generator expression `(2 ** k for k in range(x))`. The problem here is that you would need to specify a value `x` which happens to be `math.floor(math.log2(20)) + 1` (because you are looking for the largest number `k` for which `2 ** k < 20` is true).

So the full expression would be this:

```
for i in (2 ** k for k in range(math.floor(math.log2(20)) + 1)):
    print(i)
```

… which is a bit messy, so if you don’t necessarily need the `i` to be those values, you could move it inside the loop body:

```
for k in range(math.floor(math.log2(20)) + 1):
    i = 2 ** k
    print(i)
```

But this still only fits your purpose. If you wanted a “real” C-for loop expression, you could write a generator function:

```
def classicForLoop (init, stop, step):
    i = init
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i = step(i)
```

Used like this:

```
for i in classicForLoop(1, 20, lambda x: x * 2):
    print(i)
```

Of course, you could also modify the generator function to take lambdas as the first and second parameter, but it’s a bit simpler like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use range() function to define iteration length.You can directly use print() than system.out.println

Alexander mentioned it and re-iterating

```
 for i in range(1,20):print(i*2)
```

You can also consider while loop here-

```
 i=0     
 while (i<20):   
      print(2**i)     
      i=i+1
```

Remember indentation in python

Comment: your while loop is wrong, it gives i as 2,3,6,8,10 and so on, i just need 1,2,4,8,etc powers of 2 you see

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question what output you seeked.Have modified the while loop to give the desired result